# How to keep parent element height not changed whether child exist in tailwind css?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have following html code:

```
<div id="bar" class="p-4 bg-white">
  <div class="flex justify-between">
    <h3 class="text-2xl font-bold text-left text-black">Users</h3>
    <a class="py-2 px-4 text-sm font-extralight rounded shadow-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-opacity-75 bg-blue-500 text-white hover:bg-blue-700 focus:ring-blue-400" href="/admin/users/new">New user</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I found when I remove "New user" button ("a" tag), the **div#bar element**'s height will change a little smaller.

[image]

After I remove right "New user button" ("a" tag), the **div#bar element**'s height changed:

[image]

I need div#bar element keep its height whether its child element "New user" button exist.

Because I want to have a centralized page layout, some of my page header contains right button, other may not contains right button.

How to avoid child element's padding affect its parent actual height?

Comment: Have you tried adding fixed height to the parent element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either add some padding on the `h3` to make it same height or bigger than the button, that way adding button won't increase container height.

Or you can just set some minimal height on the container.

[Check this Tailwind playground I've made](https://play.tailwindcss.com/EOjdyXgQsg)

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

give it a parent min height.

```
min-h-something
```